# ListPreference android 2.3.3 setIcon : NoSuchMethodError

Tags: java, android, nosuchmethoderror, listpreference

Very weird bug

I use ListPreference on android. And when using setIcon() method for it in the Samsung gio s5660 with android 2.3.3 I've got :

```
    05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.preference.ListPreference.setIcon
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at com.assignmentexpert.AssignmentPref.enableOnlyAssignmentProduct(AssignmentPref.java:2022)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at com.assignmentexpert.AssignmentPref.onResume(AssignmentPref.java:2003)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1150)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:3832)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2114)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.moveToState(LocalActivityManager.java:170)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.LocalActivityManager.startActivity(LocalActivityManager.java:321)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.widget.TabHost$IntentContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:676)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:348)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:141)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:456)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
05-23 14:14:31.169: E/AndroidRuntime(1572):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

weirdness is that when I launch it in the Nexus 7, it works properly. The same code base !!!

What wrong with it ?

Comment: did you check ListPreference documentation ...  next time, please, do some research befor asking

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no effort in research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You minising for me. ok. But it's better to give some available solutions to the problem. But it is easier to place minuses.

This is solution for the ListPreference, workable for lower then HoneyComb android too :

```
public class IconPreference extends ListPreference {

private Drawable mIcon;

public IconPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public IconPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setLayoutResource(R.layout.icon_pref);
    TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
            R.styleable.IconPreference, defStyle, 0);
    mIcon = a.getDrawable(R.styleable.IconPreference_icon);
}

@Override
public void onBindView(View view) {
    super.onBindView(view);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon);
    if (imageView != null && mIcon != null) {
        imageView.setImageDrawable(mIcon);
    }
}

public void setIcon(Drawable icon) {
    if ((icon == null && mIcon != null) || (icon != null && !icon.equals(mIcon))) {
        mIcon = icon;
        notifyChanged();
    }
}

public Drawable getIcon() {
    return mIcon;
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

The `setIcon` method was added in API 11 so if you try to call it in API<11 then you will get an `NoSuchMethodError`